# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-General' for key

Tags: database, setup-upgrade, eav-attributes, magento2.4.0

Run the upgrade command, and the issue should be face

> sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade

Return during the process:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-General' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_NAME', query was: UPDATE `eav_attribute_group` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `attribute_group_name` = ?, `default_id` = ? WHERE (`attribute_group_id`='7')

I try this link but it's not working

https://cybersolutions-llc.com/blog/integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-4-images-key-magento-2/

Comment: Now you can add **eav_attribute_group** table attribute_group_name field group name General defult_id set 1;

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a row to the `eav_attribute_group` table that already exists. The link you referenced to is deleting another row from the table.

Possibility is to remove the correct row from table
`delete from eav_attribute_group WHERE attribute_group_name = 'General' AND attribute_set_id = 4;`

After that, you should be able to run setup:upgrade again.

Please create a backup before you do this, because I'm not totally sure if you're attribute groups will keep working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can add **eav_attribute_group** table attribute_group_name field group name General defult_id set 1;